# Put/Place On Anbiotics

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, register

I have a question about the difference between verbs "***put***" and "***place***" in this context:

> 1. The doctor ***put*** him ***on*** antibiotics.
> 2. The doctor ***placed*** him ***on*** antibiotics.

Any difference between "*put*" and "*place*"?

Comment: No real difference. "Put" is more colloquial whilst "placed is probably more correct.

Comment: ["Placed" is more common than "put" in writing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+on+antibiotics%2Cplaced+on+antibiotics&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), which surprises me.  "Put" seems more natural to me, but that's probably because it's more colloquial.  This is borne out by the fact that ["put" is more common in fiction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+on+antibiotics%2Cplaced+on+antibiotics&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=16&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20on%20antibiotics%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @stangdon: Sounds like a good basis for an answer!

Comment: *He was put on notice. He was placed on notice*.  **Placed** is  far less colloquial (corroborating @stangdon). To my ear, it sounds stilted, as if it were simply avoiding the word **put**.